# 2000 Jeep Grand Cherokee 4.0 200k miles - 02 Sensor and cylinder 5 misfire code come on at the same time

Tags: engine, jeep, misfire

People keep telling me it can't be an 02 sensor, and other people keep telling me that an 02 sensor has given them a misfire so I'm not sure what to do. I've replaced the plugs (old ones were in bad condition, obviously old, covered in build up, cheap champion plugs) and it's still misfiring. I tried clearing the codes but still running rough (only ran it for a minute or 2 after clearing codes if that matters). My question is, what do I try next? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[Screenshot of codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpZgH.png)

Comment: Have you done a compression test? Try unplugging the upstream o2. See if it runs better.

Comment: Also, have you checked the ignition coils?

Comment: "02 sensor has given them a misfire" O2 sensors are not used to set misfire codes.